# How to denote raising $x^1$ to a power in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

I'm working from a text in which the coordinates of a point in $\mathbb R^n$ are denoted $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$. I'm wondering if there is a standard way to denote the sum of the squares of these coordinates. For example, should I write
$$
{x^1}^2 + \dots + {x^n}^2,
$$
which doesn't seem very clear, or should I write
$$
(x^1)^2 + \dots + (x^n)^2?
$$

Comment: Probably not the first. I'm not familiar with the notation the text uses, but the first option you propose seems very wrong.

Comment: I suppose for the sum of squares you could use $|x|^2$, but then what to do for other powers becomes the question.

Comment: You could denote the point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $(x_1, ..., x_n)$ and then denote the sum of squares by $x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right,

$${x^1}^2+\dots+{x^n}^2$$

is hard to understand (although not really ambiguous once you've looked at it for long enough) but

$${(x^1)}^2+\dots+{(x^n)}^2$$

is totally clear.

(You could also write $x^1x^1+\dots+x^nx^n$ or $\sum_i x^ix^i$ or $\sum_i(x^i)^2$.)